# NoSuchElementException: No Line Found, while reading in text file

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I'm currently working on building a text adventure game, and I've run into a problem while trying to read in text files that contain the descriptions of the room. Whenever I run the program, I can properly read in and assign the first text file, but the second one throws the following error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at Input.getInput(Input.java:9)
    at Room.buildRoom(Room.java:92)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

I'm not at all sure what is causing this. I've tried moving things around, but to no avail. Below is the function that I'm calling on the room object itself to assign all information to it.

```
public void buildRoom(int num, String name, Room north,
        Room south, Room east, Room west) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out
            .println("Please input the location of the file you'd like to read in. Please note that you must read in the files in numerical order, or your game will not work.");

    String input = Input.getInput();

    File file = new File(input);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

    String description = reader.next();
    this.setDescription(description);

    this.setNorthExit(north);
    this.setSouthExit(south);
    this.setEastExit(east);
    this.setWestExit(west);
    reader.close();
}
```

Any help with figuring out just why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. If you've got any questions feel free to ask and I will answer to the best of my ability.

EDIT: The input function is as follows...

```
public static String getInput() {

    System.out.print("> ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = in.nextLine();
    input.toLowerCase();
    in.close();
    return input;
}
```

Comment: So where you provide file name from which to read data ?

Comment: Can we see what `Input` is and how it is created?

Comment: @Tdorno: Yes exactly. I also want to know about `Input`.

Comment: Edit: Edited it into the OP.

Comment: So are getting input data to buildRoom method ? Have you check it?

Comment: I know this works because the first time I call it in my main function (on a Room object called room1) it works just fine. The second time however I don't even get a chance to input anything before the error shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't keep closing std input every time you call the `getInput` method. `Scanner::close` closes the underlying stream.

Create the `Scanner` outside and keep using it. Create it somewhere where it lives till the last time you call `getInput`.

Pass the `Scanner` object to the `getInput` method.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(whatever)
{
     String s = getInput(sc);
     ....

}
sc.close();

public static String getInput(Scanner in) 
{
    System.out.print("> ");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    input.toLowerCase();
    return input;
}
```